# Efficient method to find n-th most frequent value subject to a condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an array formula that works but it is slow to calculate and I doubt it is the most efficient way to do this. To simplify the problem, say column A is "location" and column B is "person", I want to determine, for a specified location, the person that is both associated with that location AND the n-th most frequently associated with any location (i.e. across all locations). To help my formula, I define column C for every entry as the `COUNT` of column B for the person in that row (i.e. it equals the total number of associations for the person in that row).

Uses `IF ( A = TargetPerson, C)` to generate an array which is false A is not the TargetPerson and is the count (C) if it is the TargetPerson.

Takes the `MAX` of the above.

Uses `MATCH` to look up the above determined max, where the lookup range is the same array calculated in the first step above.

Uses `INDEX` to return column B for the matched row.

The problems with this:

- It seems slow.
- I am struggling to generalize it to identify the n-th most frequently occurring person; I tried `LARGE` in lieu of `MAX` but it breaks down if you have two equally frequently occurring individuals - in that case I would like to be able to return them both based on an an alpha sort for example.

Grateful for any tips.

Was asked for reproducible example. No idea how to provide data through this...

Data:

```
A           B               C = count of person B for the full column B
Location    Person
New York    Luke Skywalker
New York    Darth Vader
New York    Carrie Fisher
London  Carrie Fisher
Cairo   Mark Hammill
Dublin  Mark Hammill
Sydney  Mark Hammill
Melbourne   Carrie Fisher
```

Formula in Sheet2, which has rows for each unique location (col A) and tries to return the person associated with that location who is also most frequently associated with any location (in col B):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9,MATCH(MAX(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9=Sheet2!A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9)),IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9=Sheet2!A4,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9),0),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a fairly quick function BUT you need to park an intermediate result somewhere. For some reason I cant pass the result of `FILTER` into a second `FILTER`

So I put the first `FILTER` into `E5` and then pass that into the second filter

```
E5
=FILTER(A5:C12, A5:A12=$B$1)
```

and

```
I5
=FILTER(E5#, G5:G7=LARGE(OFFSET(E5#, 0, 2, COUNTIF(A5:A12, B1), 1), B2))
```

Steps are:

1. Filter the input list based on location
2. Isolate the counts (the filter output, what was the original column C) using `offset` and identify the value of the nth largest using `LARGE` and user input `Person Rank`
3. Filter the intermediate array based on the value associated with the nth largest

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it seems `FILTER` is only available in Office365 which I am not using.